# Error 403 - I'm not able to install plugin any more on WP

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, admin, http-status-code-403

There are an error in the script on admin.php I fixed it and check all permission are correctly set. Since then I'm not able to install a plugin in my WP. I'm lost - Someone can help me, please?

My host told me there are no problem on the server

I want to install a plugin but I have error 403

My current script on admin.php is below and permission 755

```
<?php
/**
 * WordPress Administration Bootstrap
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
}
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php';

// If the user is not an administrator, do not proceed
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
}

// Add necessary scripts and styles
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts' );
function my_admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-admin' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'common' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-lists' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'postbox' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-dialog' );
}

// Allow administrators to install and activate plugins
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', ( 0755 & ~ umask() ) );
define( 'FS_CHMOD_FILE', ( 0644 & ~ umask() ) );
define( 'FS_CONNECT_TIMEOUT', 30 );
define( 'FS_TIMEOUT', 30 );

// Disable automatic updates
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );

// Allow all file types to be uploaded
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_custom_upload_mimes' );
function my_custom_upload_mimes( $mime_types ) {
    $mime_types['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    $mime_types['webp'] = 'image/webp';

    return $mime_types;
}
```

and .htaccess script is below and permission set at 644:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch ".*\.(py|exe|phtml|php|PHP|Php|PHp|pHp|pHP|phP|PhP|php5|suspected)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(index.php|wp-login.php|profile.php|load-styles.php|load-scripts.php|plugins.php|plugin-install.php|wp-head.php|wp-site.php)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be found in your htaccess file in the following block.

```
<FilesMatch ".*\.(py|exe|phtml|php|PHP|Php|PHp|pHp|pHP|phP|PhP|php5|suspected)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

it states that access to all files with the extensions in bracket should be denied. so remove that block and everything should work